# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener"

Tags: flutter, dart, google-mobile-ads

could you assist in this issue which faced when i was trying to implement "google_mobile_ads" shown after debugging my flutter app since the app had been built succesfully but the connection had lost and there was no issue in flutter doctor

> E/AndroidRuntime(12485): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> Didn't find class
> "com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener"
> on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/~~NSY8q-IBctGxJYGXJzXLcA==/com.kids_learning_A_E-0Pc0rDeeHmisujXxSpOMaQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~NSY8q-IBctGxJYGXJzXLcA==/com.kids_learning_A_E-0Pc0rDeeHmisujXxSpOMaQ==/lib/arm64,
> /data/app/~~NSY8q-IBctGxJYGXJzXLcA==/com.kids_learning_A_E-0Pc0rDeeHmisujXxSpOMaQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
> /system/lib64]] E/AndroidRuntime(12485): at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12485): at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12485): at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12485): ... 21 more I/Process (12485): Sending
> signal. PID: 12485 SIG: 9 Error handling 'checkPlatformOverride'
> custom request: method not available: ext.flutter.platformOverride
> Error handling 'checkBrightnessOverride' custom request: method not
> available: ext.flutter.brightnessOverride Error handling
> 'serviceExtension' custom request: method not available:
> ext.flutter.inspector.setPubRootDirectories Error handling
> 'checkIsWidgetCreationTracked' custom request: Bad state: No element
> Lost connection to device. Exited (sigterm)

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

**It's happend when adding the below code to intiate and implement google_mobile_ads to my flutter app**

```
void main() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
MobileAds.instance.initialize();
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**pubspec.yaml** dependencies

```
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  draggable_widget: ^1.1.1  
  services: ^0.0.1  
  audioplayers: ^0.18.3  
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.0.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0
```

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant code from your application?

Comment: void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}    It just hapened when adding the implementation of    google_mobile_ads in man function

Comment: the dependencies of pubspec.yaml  environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  draggable_widget: ^1.1.1  
  services: ^0.0.1  
  audioplayers: ^0.18.3  
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.0.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0

Comment: Please edit the question with those details.

Comment: Did you import the google package in your main.dart file?

Comment: Yes , Already imported

Answer (score 0):

From the data you have posted, you are not using the most up to date version of the [Google AdMob plugin for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/install). Your version is 0.11.0 and the newest one is 0.13.0.

I would highly suggest you upgrade this plugin and see if this fixes your issue.

You might also want to consider going over the [Get Stared guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/quick-start?hl=en) to make sure you haven't missed anything.

Furthermore, when researching online , I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/RhIxfB3gnn4) related to the problem you are having in Unity. It seems there has been a deprecation and a creation of a new initialization API and I think that the current version of the plugin is not suited for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I already had used the last version of google_mobile_ads but same issue had faced pluse another issue related to firebase although i didn't use or implement firbase at all .